# azure app service plan memory abstraction

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

Does the Azure app service(specifically App service plan) offering provide memory abstraction?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/

If i create an app service with say 2 standard skew instances(1 CPU 1.75 giga bytes memory), Does that mean i have 2 * 1.75 giga bytes memory at my app's disposal? Can i create a jvm that has heap size of 2 gig in that plan for instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify two instances within an App Service plan, that's exactly what you get: Two instances, each having the spec of the size you chose for the App Service plan. They are not bridgeable into a single virtual double-size instance.

So, no - you cannot combine the resources of the two instances. If you need more memory, you'd need to choose a larger instance size.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just wondering if the memory is conceptually pooled. Getting 2 gig out of 3.5 is reasonable if it is indeed abstracted

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'conceptually pooled' - if you have an app service plan with multiple instances, just picture each instance as its own VM (not that it is necessarily deployed that way, but logically it is). There is no way to get 2gb from a 1.75gb sku.

Comment: You are correct. I was baffled when i was able to actually create a 2 gig jvm with 2 S1 instances. But turns out 64 bit VM's will let you do that.Granted it is really bad for performance.